# Angular: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError child component & FormControl

Tags: angular

I've seen, read and tried a lot of questions, answers and blogs about this topic. I understand why it is happening in my code, I just don't know how to fix it.

(Simplification of real code; If I made mistakes or forgot something important, please let me know in the comments)

I have parent component A with an input and child component B.

```
<form [formgroup]="modalForm">
   <input type="text" formControlName="text"></input>
   <componentB 
    [formControl]="modalForm.controls['componentB'] 
    [firstProperty]="foo" 
    [secondProperty]="bar">
   </componentB>
</form>
```

ComponentB has an input as well, and a custom message component:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" [formControl]="formControl"></input>
   <message
    [message]="firstProperty" 
    [secondMessage]="secondProperty">
   </message>
</div>
```

ComponentA:

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit{

  public foo: string;
  public bar: string;
  public modalFrom: FormGroup;

  public constructor(private componentBValidatorFactory: ComponentBValidatorFactory){}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.modalForm = new FormGroup({
     text: new FormControl(null),
     componentB: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: Validators.required,
        asyncValidatiors: [this.componentBValidatorFactory.asyncValidatorFn()],
        updateOn: 'blur'
        })
    });
  this.modalForm.controls['text'].valueChanges(subscribe( () => this.textChanged());
  this.modalForm.controls['componentB'].valueChanges(subscribe( () => this.componentBChanged());
  }

  private textChanged(): void {
  this.foo = this.modalForm.controls['text'].value;
  }

  private componentBChanged(): void {
  this.bar = this.modalForm.controls['componentB'].value + 'somestring';
  }
}
```

ComponentB (simplified):

```
export class ComponentB{

@Input()
public formControl: FormControl;

@Input()
public firstProperty: string;

@Input()
public secondProperty: string;

}
```

The issue (as I understand it):
When `text` changes (user input), it updates `foo` with a value. This means that `ComponentB` changes, so `valueChanges` of ComponentB is triggered. `ComponentBChanged` is fired and it updates `bar`.
When `text` changes again, `bar` is changed again, but as it is different from the earlier value when `foo` is processed the second time, I get the well known `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` (values are processed correctly though).
As I understand it:
`ComponentB` was already updated (`foo`), which triggers another change in a binding of this same component (`bar`). Which does not make Angular happy.
Directly putting input in `ComponentB` (which also has an input field) works fine, it updates `bar` correctly without problems.

What can I do to be able to update `bar` without issues? I can't update `bar` in `textChanged` in my code as the update should also happen if `ComponentB` is manipulated directly.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqxu5j. Though it doesn't include the async validator, or the message component.

Comment: It's possible I forgot something in my simplification, or the problem is not what I think it is... I'm a little clueless atm. It seems that `bar` is not updated at all in the example?

Comment: `bar` does get updated, but only on blur. Can you add more code to the stackblitz until the issue reappears?

Comment: I tried to update the stackblitz, but I realized that the problem is probably in directives added do the input of componentB. Which are too complicated to put up here. The question helped me to get this insight, but it is rather useless for others I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing FormControl to child Use then assign the foo and bar property to null

**formControlDirective**

> This directive accepts an existing FormGroup instance. It will then
>   use this FormGroup instance to match any child FormControl, FormGroup,
>   and FormArray instances to child FormControlName, FormGroupName, and
>   FormArrayName directives.

Parent.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <label >Text</label>
  <input formControlName="text">
  <app-component-a 
  [firstProperty]="foo" 
    [secondProperty]="bar"
  ></app-component-a>
</form>
```

**app-component-a.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a',
  templateUrl: './component-a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-a.component.css'],
  viewProviders:[{provide: ControlContainer,useExisting:FormGroupDirective}]
})
export class ComponentAComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input('firstProperty') firstProperty:string;
 @Input('secondProperty') secondProperty:string;

  constructor(private fgd:FormGroupDirective) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fgd.form.addControl('componentA',new FormControl('',{updateOn: 'blur'}))
  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-65nmvr

Comment: Why is this a better option? I'm not familiar with the FormGroupDirective. However, I'm afraid I'm stuck with the way the formControl is set, due to other dependencies I did not incorporate in my example.